# Akka Streams: how to count distinct values in different sources

Tags: scala, akka-stream

I have `N` (this may be different on each materialization) finite sorted sources of numbers. I need the result as a stream of these numbers with the count of how many times they appear.

For example:

```
1,3,5,7 -> |   |
1,5,7   -> | ? | -> (1,2),(2,1),(3,1),(4,1),(5,3),(7,2)
2,4,5   -> |   |
```

How can this be implemented?

Comment: Now I have implemented some different logic (but common to the question) based on Merge graph. All works (but needs some refining). So, may be it may be implemented without own graph?

Comment: Do you mean: without using Graph DSL? Yes, see my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically you combine several sources into one and then aggregate data.
Here is a helper object and method which I use to combine several sources:

```
object ConcatSources {
  def apply[T](sources: Seq[Source[T, NotUsed]]): Source[T, NotUsed] = {

    sources match {
      case first :: second :: rest =>
        Source.combine(first, second, rest: _*)(Concat(_))
      case first :: _ =>
        first
      case Nil =>
        Source.empty
    }
  }
}
```

Then solution to your task:

```
  val sources: Seq[Source[Int, NotUsed]] = Seq(
    Source[Int](List(1, 3, 5, 7)),
    Source[Int](List(1, 5, 7)),
    Source[Int](List(2, 4, 5))
    )
  ConcatSources(sources).fold(Map[Int, Int]()) { (map, i) =>
    map.updated(i, map.getOrElse(i, 0) + 1)
  }.runForeach(map => println(map.toList))
```

Comment: As I understand correctly, you simply `concat` and `fold` streams using `memory`, like "source to list, then list + list, then process big list". Is this a `stream processing`?

Comment: I try implement something like `Inner Join` for ordered streams, so I try preserve order also for further processing

Comment: Hi Andrey, please see comments on Source.combine and Flow.fold methods, I don't see a reason why it should not be a stream processing.

Comment: You are right, there is a materialization with Map only. I simplified a question for my real task, so your answer is right for original question.

Answer (score 2):

The other answer concatenates all the sources into a single stream...

```
1,3,5,7,1,5,7,2,4,5
```

...and accumulates via a fold a map of the elements and their respective counts. The entire stream must be consumed in order to calculate the counts: in other words, one cannot know the number of occurrences of any integer without consuming the entire stream.

Another approach is to use [`Source#mergeSorted`](https://doc.akka.io/api/akka/2.5/akka/stream/scaladsl/Source.html#mergeSorted[U%3E:Out,M](that:akka.stream.Graph[akka.stream.SourceShape[U],M])(implicitord:Ordering[U]):FlowOps.this.Repr[U]) to merge the pre-sorted streams into a single stream that is sorted...

```
1,1,2,3,4,5,5,5,7,7
```

...then use [`statefulMapConcat`](https://doc.akka.io/api/akka/2.5/akka/stream/scaladsl/Source.html#statefulMapConcat[T](f:()=%3EOut=%3Escala.collection.immutable.Iterable[T]):FlowOps.this.Repr[T]) to produce the counts:

```
val src1 = Source(List(1, 3, 5, 7))
val src2 = Source(List(1, 5, 7))
val src3 = Source(List(2, 4, 5))

def mergeSortedSources(sources: List[Source[Int, NotUsed]]): Source[Int, NotUsed] =
  sources.foldLeft(Source.empty[Int])(_ mergeSorted _)
         .concat(Source.single(0)) // this ending element is needed to print the last pair

mergeSortedSources(List(src1, src2, src3))
  .statefulMapConcat { () =>
    var prev: Option[Int] = None
    var count = 0

    x =>
      prev match {
        case None | Some(`x`) =>
          count = count + 1
          prev = Some(x)
          Nil
        case Some(oldElem) =>
          val oldCount = count
          count = 1
          prev = Some(x)
          (oldElem -> oldCount) :: Nil
      }
  }.runForeach(println)
```

Running the above code prints the following:

```
(1,2)
(2,1)
(3,1)
(4,1)
(5,3)
(7,2)
```

Since the merged stream is sorted, the counts are calculated in successive order as the stream is processed. That is, the number of occurrences of `1` is determined before the number of occurrences of `2` is determined, and so on.